# Get combined difference (not common/"intersecting" records) from two queries

Tags: sql

**Database -** Microsoft Adventureworks

**Tables -** 
Sales.SalesOrderHeader

**Problem -** Which customers (ie customerID's) ordered something in March 2003 or April 2003 but not both.

**Concept -**

Get the blue parts, ie elements/rows *unique* to A and those *unique* to B. 
[image: Image Credits - Jeff Atwood of CodingHorror.com]

**My query -**

```
select Soh.CustomerID, Soh.OrderDate 
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Soh
where Soh.OrderDate >= '2003-03-01' AND Soh.OrderDate < '2003-04-01' -- march only

UNION

select Soh.CustomerID, Soh.OrderDate 
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Soh
where Soh.OrderDate >= '2003-04-01' AND Soh.OrderDate < '2003-05-01' -- april only    
order by Soh.OrderDate asc;
```

**My questions -**

Did I answer the problem correctly ? 
Any other ways of solving this problem, preferably lesser amount of code ?

**EDIT -** Ooops. This will only give orders in the 2 months and not answer the question. So, I am wrong. Trying to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Credits for image goes to - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Shoot, the correct term for this is escaping me :>

Comment: @user2246674 - lol. me too. btw, can you get a human name. Your name sounds like that of a robot.

Comment: He is a robot.  Many on the Stack Exchange sites are. :P

Comment: This would be a nice question for CodeReview.StackExchange.com :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  Cust.CustomerID
FROM    Sales.Customer AS Cust
        INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS Soh
            ON Cust.CustomerID = Soh.CustomerID
WHERE   Soh.OrderDate >= '2003-03-01' AND Soh.OrderDate < '2003-05-01'
GROUP   BY Cust.CustomerID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(Soh.OrderDate) = 3 AND
                                YEAR(Soh.OrderDate) = 2003 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*simplified records*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d375c/3)

Well, `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` are pretty self explanatory. The tricky part here is the `HAVING` clause. So let me simplify it, the `CASE` statement you see gives a value which categorized the record into a group. Instead of `1` and `2`, I will be using `March` and `April` to make it more understandable.

```
SELECT  CustomerID,
        CASE WHEN MONTH(OrderDate) = 3 AND YEAR(OrderDate) = 2003 
              THEN 'March' 
              ELSE 'April'
        END AS MonthBought
FROM    TableName
WHERE   OrderDate >= '2003-03-01' AND OrderDate < '2003-05-01'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d375c/4)

As you can see in the demo, when the date of order falls in the month of `March, 2013` of any date, the corresponding value of `MonthBought` is `March`, other wise `April` since we are sure that all records fall between `March and April 2013` because of the `WHERE` clause.

The `HAVING` clause filters all records which has the number of unique value in the `MonthBought` to only `1` which means the customer bought only on a certain month.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d375c/7)

Comment: I edited the query in my question. Very sorry to bring this up so late. Can you modify the answer as per the new question ? Thanks.

Comment: yes, 746 rows. I tried another query (super long) and got 746 rows too. I did that because I did not understand the logic behind your answer. Can you explain it please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE table_a ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   , OrderDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2003-03-15');
CREATE TABLE table_b ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   , OrderDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2003-04-15');

INSERT INTO table_a(id) VALUES (0),(2),(4),(6),(8),(10),(12),(14),(16),(18),(20);
INSERT INTO table_b(id) VALUES (0),(3),(6),(9),(12),(15),(18),(21);


SELECT COALESCE (a.id, b.id) AS id
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM table_a
        WHERE OrderDate >= '2003-03-01' AND OrderDate < '2003-04-01'
        ) a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM table_b
        WHERE OrderDate >= '2003-04-01' AND OrderDate < '2003-05-01'
        )  b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL OR b.id IS NULL
        ;
```

Note: I had to invent my own data, since the OP did not supply any, and I am too lazy to type it in.

UPDATE: the original UNION query (here with the table_a/table_b construct, for the original data model, use table_a = table_b = `Sales.SalesOrderHeader`)

```
SELECT a.id, a.OrderDate
FROM table_a as a
WHERE a.OrderDate >= '2003-03-01' AND a.OrderDate < '2003-04-01' -- march only
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table_b nx
        WHERE nx.id = a.id
        AND nx.OrderDate >= '2003-04-01' AND nx.OrderDate < '2003-05-01' -- april only
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT b.id, b.OrderDate
FROM table_b as b
WHERE b.OrderDate >= '2003-04-01' AND b.OrderDate < '2003-05-01' -- april only    
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table_a nx
        WHERE nx.id = b.id
        AND nx.OrderDate >= '2003-03-01' AND nx.OrderDate < '2003-04-01' -- march only
        )
ORDER BY OrderDate ASC;
```

Notes:

- the `UNION` should be a `UNION ALL`, since duplicates are impossible, and don't have to be removed
- The `NOT EXISTS ()` clauses are necessary: you want the records in march that don't exist in april, and vice versa.
- the need for `UNION` is often an indication of a sub-optimal data model (in this case it is not)
- `FULL OUTER JOIN` can be considered a special form of relational division

Comment: AdventureWorks comes with SQL Server,...unless you didn't install it with your SQL instance of course...

Comment: Stack Overflow does not come with AdventureWorks, unless you installed it, of course ...

Comment: Lol! Right, I kind of assumed you had ssms in front of you there.. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

No, you did not answer the problem correctly. "Union" gave you all the results from the first query (A) and all the results of the second query, where the results were not already returned.

Nice graphic though!

Comment: I dont have the AdventureWorks database installed but I did the same thing with an errorlog I have looking for forms that caused an error last year but not this year: SELECT ErrorDate
      ,FormIn
  FROM ErrorLog
  where ErrorDate between '1/1/2012' and '12/31/2012'
  and FormIn not in (SELECT FormIn
  FROM ErrorLog
  where ErrorDate between '1/1/2013' and '12/31/2013')

Comment: Or do what '491243' did in his post.  I like his better!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it finally. Answer - 746 rows with query -

```
-- Customers who had an order on Mar or Apr, but not both
select Ord.CustomerID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Ord
where (Ord.OrderDate >= '2003-03-01' AND Ord.OrderDate < '2003-04-01') -- all March
or (Ord.OrderDate >= '2003-04-01' AND Ord.OrderDate < '2003-05-01') -- all April

except 

select MarchAndApril.CustomerID
from
(
select Ord.CustomerID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Ord
where (Ord.OrderDate >= '2003-03-01' AND Ord.OrderDate < '2003-04-01') -- March

intersect

select Ord.CustomerID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Ord
where (Ord.OrderDate >= '2003-04-01' AND Ord.OrderDate < '2003-05-01') -- April
) as MarchAndApril

order by Ord.CustomerID
```

---

Here is a different sample data set to make things easy.

Table - Orders

Columns - CustomerID(PK, int, Not null), OrderDate(date, not null)
Orders only on jan, feb, july.

```
1   2012-01-01
1   2012-01-02
1   2012-02-01
2   2012-01-01
2   2012-02-01
3   2012-01-01
4   2012-02-01
5   2012-07-01
```

New question - get customers who had orders on jan or feb, but not both.

Strategy - Get the customers for jan and feb. Then, from that set, remove customers who had orders on both jan and feb.

We expect the results to be 3,4. That is indeed the case.

```
-- Customers who had an order on Jan or Feb, but not both
select Ord.CustomerID
from Orders as Ord
where (Ord.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01' AND Ord.OrderDate < '2012-02-01') -- all January
or (Ord.OrderDate >= '2012-02-01' AND Ord.OrderDate < '2012-03-01') -- all February

--We can replace this where + or by a UNION ??? I got the same results, ie 3,4

except 

select JanuaryAndFebruary.CustomerID
from
(
select Ord.CustomerID
from Orders as Ord
where (Ord.OrderDate >= '2012-01-01' AND Ord.OrderDate < '2012-02-01') -- January

intersect

select Ord.CustomerID
from Orders as Ord
where (Ord.OrderDate >= '2012-02-01' AND Ord.OrderDate < '2012-03-01') -- February
) as JanuaryAndFebruary

order by Ord.CustomerID
```